# Vector Drawables vs Bitmap in terms of RAM (Android)

Tags: android, memory, vector, bitmap, ram

In terms of RAM utilized by a drawable when it is rendered on on the screen, does it make any difference if the drawable is a vector or a bitmap?

I understand that vectors take less media storage space, but I'm asking about the resident RAM needed in order to render it, since in theory, it is still being drawn onto a canvas with the same amount of pixels in the end.

Thanks!

Comment: `VectorDrawable` internally uses a `Bitmap` for faster re-drawing so it doesnt really differ from a `BitmapDrawable` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the document I read sometime ago (same question with you).
The different between these 2 options is the size of APK file after all when you release. SVG will help you save size of apk.

`The initial loading of a vector graphic can cost more CPU cycles than the corresponding raster image. Afterward, memory use and performance are similar between the two. We recommend that you limit a vector image to a maximum of 200 x 200 dp; otherwise, it can take too long to draw.`

Being drawn on view will have those 2 options having same RAM (memory) consumed.

My reference source: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about

Answer (score 0):

use vector drawables for simple shapes. Using the same for complex structures will increase the size of the apk rapidly.